# Laravel: ignore case when using string primary key in relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a new project using Laravel where I need to use data from a legacy database(so please ignore the database design).

This database is using the username as primary key:

[image]

The **User** model has a One To Many relationshio with "**ChangeContract**" model

```
/**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function changesContract(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ChangeContract::class, 'Username', 'UserName')->latestFirst();
    }
```

The current user has multiple contract changes:

[image]

But only two Contract Changes are returned by the relationship, the ones that matach the primary key(user name) exactly(case sensitive):

```
   "changesContract": [
        {
            "type": "Contract Change",
            "username": "FroneaBA",
            "date": "2017-10-01",
            "endDate": "2018-06-30"
        },
        {
            "type": "Contract Change",
            "username": "FroneaBA",
            "date": "2017-07-01",
            "endDate": "2017-09-30"
        }
    ],
```

I need also to return the items where the key is **froneaba**.
Is there a way to set the primary key to be case insensitive?

P.S: From the database client, if I write the query by hand, all the items are returned:

```
SELECT * FROM changescontract WHERE username='froneaba';
```

Comment: use the `LIKE` keyword to check the string without considering its Upper or Lower case.

Comment: @odaiwa can you post an example on how this would work in a relationship?

Comment: In my opinion this is not a duplicated questions, I fixed it using this library: https://github.com/TishoTM/eloquent-ci-relations, please vote  reopen

Comment: @odaiwa In most database system, `LIKE` is not case insensitive (unless a case-insensitive collation is used)